# ok and cancel buttons on showinputdialog and jlist

Tags: jlist, joptionpane

I have an add button that adds entries to a txt file, and a jlist that is populated by the txt file. The jlist is refreshed immediately when an entry is added. The add button utilizes showinputdialog for the user to add an entry and here lays the problem:

1) I understand that when the cancel button is pressed, joptionpane returns null. How do i make it so that it doesn't actually add "null" to the txt file and the jlist when i press cancel?

2) Also, similar problem, if I don't input anything and press the enter button, the program adds an empty entry to the txt file that also show up on the jlist. How do I make it so that if no input is entered and the ok button is pressed, a prompt pops up and tells the user to enter a valid input?

Here's what I've got so far...

```
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String entry = "\n" + JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter part number");

            if(entry.equals(null))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid entry", "Blank entry!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

            }
```

The if statement here actually doesn't do anything and I don't know why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your problem number 2.. also trim your input. you can condition your input like this:

```
String entry = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter part number");
if(entry == null){ // if the user press cancel;
  return;
}
entry = entry.trim();
if(entry.equals("") || entry.isEmpty()){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter a valid input!");
           return;
 }else{
   entry = "\n" + entry;
 }
```

Comment: so you mean the variable 'entry' return false in the condition even if the value of 'entry' is null or empty?

Comment: As i noticed.. your variable `entry` add a string "\n".. as result, your entry will always have a value of "\n" even if the user didn't input any value.. try to remove that one or add that value "\n" after your condition

Comment: Actually I'm sorry it did work! I forgot to erase the "\n". Would you happen to know what to do with question #1? I tried some if statements but maybe my logic was wrong because none of them worked :/ Also, with the code you gave me added on, I get a "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException" when I press cancel. Why's that?

Comment: the purpose of trim() is to eliminate extended spaces.. remove the trim() there.. add the trim after you ask the user input. `entry = entry.trim();`

Comment: with your #1 problem.. if you press cancel, to condition a null value add this to your condition `entry == null`.

Comment: I edited the code.. try that one.. :) 
 i condition the entry if it is null. the purpose of `return` there is to do nothing if the cancel button press

Comment: I still get a nullPointerException error when I press cancel... but the code does work! When I get the error, it highlights the line "if(entry.equals("") || entry.isEmpty())" I tried to reduce the condition to just entry.isEmpty() but it still does the same thing :/

Comment: so therefore when you press cancel it didn't get inside the `if(entry == null)` condition?. I edited my answer :)

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your effort! I tried to understand the logic but I couldn't... Why did you have entry=entry.trim() after the cancel button condition? isn't the if statement already telling the program to return and not input a "null"? So why does that solve the nullPointerException error?